# rvm install throws error while running make on macos (monterey)

Tags: ruby, makefile, rvm, macos-monterey

My terminal started saying

```
Required ruby-2.6.0 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install "ruby-2.6.0"'
```

When I tried to run the install I got the error:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j10',
please read /Users/ih143f/.rvm/log/1680671333_ruby-2.6.0/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Answer (score 0):

[This Git forum post](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5047#issuecomment-1190638988) said to run the following before running rvm install:

```
export warnflags=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration
```